# How to use enumerator list items when its identifier is already a member of struct?

Tags: c++, function, struct, enums, file-handling

My program is not responding. When i run the program it stays on the blank screen with no error and no output.

I dont know what is the mistake. How to read the enumerators from inside the struct. The following is wrong. Please help.

```
infile >> gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Status;

Error:

C:\Users\PC\Desktop\a1\ass1.cpp [Error] no match for 'operator>>' 
(operand types are 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' and 
'StatusType')
```

This is ".txt" file.

```
7453842   
Gregory  Harrison   
4   
CSCI104 0 56  
IACT111 0 44  
INFO112 0 75  
CSCI321 0 89
```

The output must be like this:

```
13 records read
Commands Available:
d - Display Record
u - Update Record
q - Quit the program
Command: d
Enter student number: 4734455
Student No. 4734455
First Name Kieren
Last Name Legrande
Subjects:
CSCI104 Provisional 65
IACT123 Enrolled 67
CSCI121 Enrolled 98
```

I want to read this data and save it and update the record as well. But, the program does not run or stays on the blank screen while showing no error. It runs but does not output anything.

.h and main.cpp are both fine. 
but i am having issue with this coding file.
Here is my coding:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
// ============== Constants ==========================================

const char cTextFileName[]   = "ass1.txt";
const char cBinaryFileName[] = "ass1.dat";
const int cMaxRecs = 100;
const int cMaxChars = 30;
const int cMaxSubjects = 8;

// ============= User Defined types ==================================

enum StatusType{eEnrolled,eProvisional,eWithdrawn};
struct SubjectType{ char Code[8]; StatusType Status; int Mark;};

struct StudentRecord{
    long StudentNo;
    char FirstName[cMaxChars];
    char LastName[cMaxChars];
    int NumSubjects;
    SubjectType Subjects[cMaxSubjects];
};


// ============= Global Data =========================================

StudentRecord gRecs[cMaxRecs];
int gNumRecs=0;


// ============= Private Function Prototypes =========================

void PrintRecord(int i);
int FindRecord(long StudentNum);

// ============= Public Function Definitions =========================


void ReadFile()
{ // Reads data file into array

int i =0;
StatusType items;

ifstream infile;
infile.open("ass1.txt");
if (!infile.good())
{
    cerr << "There is an error opening a file.";
    exit(1);
}
infile >> gRecs[i].StudentNo;
while(!infile.eof())
{
    infile >> gRecs[ i].FirstName;
    infile >> gRecs[i].LastName;
    infile >> gRecs[i].NumSubjects;
    for(int j=0; j<=gRecs[i].NumSubjects;)
    {
    infile >> gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Code;

    infile >> gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Status;


    infile >> gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Mark;
    }
    i++;
    infile >> gRecs[i].StudentNo;  

    gNumRecs = i;
    infile.close();
    cout << gNumRecs << "read records " << gNumRecs;

}

}

void DisplayRecord()
{    // Displays specified record on screen

//  int stuNo;
    int i = 0;
//  int StudentNo;

//  cout << PrintRecord(i);
    cout << "Enter Student Number :";
    cin >> gRecs[i].StudentNo;

    i=FindRecord(gRecs[i].StudentNo);
    if(!FindRecord(gRecs[i].StudentNo));
    {
     cout << "Sorry, Record not found .";
}
PrintRecord(i);    

//  cout << PrintRecord(i);


}

void SaveFile()
{// Writes array to text data file

StatusType Status;
fstream myfile;
myfile.open("ass1.txt");
if (!myfile.good())
{
    cerr << " Problem opening the data file.";
    exit(1);
}

for(int i=0; i<gNumRecs;)
{
    cout << "Student No :"   << gRecs[i].StudentNo;
    cout << "First Name :"   << gRecs[i].FirstName;
    cout << "Last Name  :"   << gRecs[i].LastName;
    cout << "Subjects   :"   << gRecs[i].NumSubjects;

    for(int j=0; j<=gRecs[i].NumSubjects;)
    {
    cout << gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Code << "  ";

    switch(Status)
    {
        case eEnrolled    : cout << "Enrolled"    << "  " << endl; break;
        case eProvisional : cout << "Provisional" << "  " << endl; break;
        case eWithdrawn   : cout << "Withdrawn"   << "  " << endl; break;
    }   
    cout << gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Mark;
    }
}
myfile.close();

cout << "Records have been saved.";

}

void UpdateRecord()
{// updates status or mark of specified subject of specified student number

int i=0;
int j=0;
//  int sub_cod;
int studentNo;
//  int stuNo;
char optn;
char s;
int m;

fstream infile;
infile.open("ass1.txt");
cout << "Enter Student Number :";
cin >> gRecs[i].StudentNo;
infile >> gRecs[i].StudentNo;

i=FindRecord(gRecs[i].StudentNo);
if(!FindRecord(gRecs[i].StudentNo))
{
    cout << "Sorry, Record not found .";
}

PrintRecord(i);
cout << "Please Enter the subject code you want to update :";
cin  >> gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Code;
if(!gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Code)
{
    cout << "Subject code not found!";
}
cout << "Select status or mark (s/m) :";
cin  >> optn;

switch(optn)
{

case 's':
    cout << "Select new status :" ;
    cout << "    "  << "e: Enrolled";
    cout << "    "  << "p: Provisional ";
    cout << "    "  << "w: Withdrawn ";
    cin  >> s;
    // need to be entered
    cout << "Status :" << s << endl;
    cout << "Record "  << i << "updated ." << endl;
    break;

case 'm':
    cout << "Enter the marks";
    cin  >> m;

    for(int j=0; j<=gRecs[i].NumSubjects;)
    {

    infile >> gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Mark;
    }
    break;

}


}


// ============= Private Function Definitions =========================

void PrintRecord(int i)
{ // Prints record i on screen

StatusType emembers;
cout << gRecs[i].StudentNo;
cout << gRecs[i].FirstName;
cout << gRecs[i].LastName;
cout << gRecs[i].NumSubjects;
for(int j=0; j<=gRecs[i].NumSubjects;)
    {
    cout << gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Code;

/*      switch(emembers)
    {
        case '0'   : cout << "Enrolled"    ; break;
        case '1'   : cout << "Provisional" << endl; break;
        case '2'   : cout << "Withdrawn"   << endl; break;
    }
*/
    cout << gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Mark;
    }

}

int FindRecord(long StudentNo)
{// returns index of matching record or -1 if not found
int i=0;
for(int i=0; i<13;)

{
    if (!gRecs[i].StudentNo && StudentNo == StudentNo)
    {
        return i;
    }

}

return -1;

}
```

Also, i am having issue with UpdateRecord() and FindRecord(). Please check for the mistake if i am making any. Guys help please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `operator >>` for your custom type.

```
template<class _CharT,class _Traits>
std::basic_istream<_CharT,_Traits>&
 operator >>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& _is, StatusType& _my_enum)
{
    int _temp;
    _is >> _temp;
    _my_enum = static_cast<StatusType>(_temp);
    return _is;
}
```

Comment: its not easy for me to understand the high level of coding at this stage. Sorry but I didnt get a single line.

Comment: your compile error was due to the `ifstream >>` dosen't support your 
self-defined type `StatusType`. Thus we override `operator >>` to make it support `StatusType`. Feel free to add this function in your cpp file after the defination of `StatusType` and compile it.

Comment: I try to put the code after StatusType and it worked (means didnt show error like beofre) but still the program runs and stays on blank screen and does not show any error not even output.

Comment: your loop variable didn't change in the for loop.it seemed that it shoud be `j < gRecs[i].NumSubjects`, not `j <= gRecs[i].NumSubjects`.

Comment: change `for (int j = 0; j <= gRecs[i].NumSubjects;)` to `for (int j = 0; j < gRecs[i].NumSubjects;++j)` in `ReadFile` ,then fix other `for` loops like this.

Comment: I appreciate your help but the the program is still stuck on a blank screen with no output no error.

Comment: oh yeah i got that the program is running now. Thanks mate (Y)